# Nav2 Behaviour Tree dies with custom planner (ROSIDLCPP_StringValueType error)

Tags: navigation, ros2, path-planning, nav2, planner

I am using Nav2 to build a custom planner based on a path of GPS coordinates which are transformed into cartesian coordinates. When I start the navigation stack and send my GPS points via a service call, everything works as intended (the points are transformed into cartesian and put into a vector). Then I call the /send_goal action to begin the createPlan function and start navigating (therefore ignoring the actual goal that I send in the action message). I can see that the points are added to the plan as PoseStamped messages and that the plan is created with a size of 32 poses, but the behavior tree dies before it begins the navigation.

I ran the BT process with gdb and got this error:

```
[gdb-1] [INFO] [1700141303.063432882] [bt_navigator]: Begin navigating from current location (0.00, 0.00) to (10.00, 10.00)
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063570260] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: [1700141303.064]:          NavigateRecovery IDLE -> RUNNING
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063613588] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: [1700141303.064]:            RateController IDLE -> RUNNING
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063630773] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: [1700141303.064]:         ComputePathToPose IDLE -> RUNNING
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063646741] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: [1700141303.064]:         ComputePathToPose IDLE -> RUNNING
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063679573] [rcl_action]: Sending action goal request
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063689814] [rcl]: Client sending service request
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063751798] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063812631] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.063782519] [rcl_action]: Action goal request sent
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064582339] [rcl_action]: Taking action status
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064616835] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064632771] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064638083] [rcl_action]: Action status taken
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064646564] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node.rclcpp_action]: Received status for unknown goal. Ignoring...
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064664548] [rcl_action]: Taking action goal response
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064671684] [rcl]: Client taking service response
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064680612] [rcl]: Client take response succeeded: true
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064684452] [rcl_action]: Action goal response taken
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064705636] [rcl_action]: Sending action result request
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064711141] [rcl]: Client sending service request
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064768037] [rcl_action]: Action result request sent
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064842150] [bt_navigator_navigate_to_pose_rclcpp_node]: [1700141303.065]:    NavigateWithReplanning IDLE -> RUNNING
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064925704] [rcl]: Subscription taking message
[gdb-1] [DEBUG] [1700141303.064972488] [rcl]: Subscription take succeeded: true
[gdb-1] 
[gdb-1] Thread 11 "bt_navigator" received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
[gdb-1] [Switching to Thread 0xffffcfffe6d0 (LWP 2639)]
[gdb-1] 0x0000fffff6459d60 in rmw_cyclonedds_cpp::ROSIDLCPP_StringValueType::data(void const*) const () from /opt/ros/humble/install/lib/librmw_cyclonedds_cpp.so
```

This is the createPlan function I am using, with cartesian_waypoints being a 2D vector of doubles. Every point is roughly 3m apart from the next one. The BT I am using is the example NavigateToPose one from Nav2 but with my planner's plugin name, of course.

```
nav_msgs::msg::Path Planner::createPlan(const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & start,
        const geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped & goal){

        //Define plan
        nav_msgs::msg::Path plan;
        RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Creating plan");

        plan.header.stamp = node_->now();
        plan.header.frame_id = "map";

        plan.poses.clear();

        // Convert list of waypoints to poses
        for (long unsigned int i=0; i<cartesian_waypoints.size(); i++){
            geometry_msgs::msg::PoseStamped pose;
            pose.header.stamp = node_->now();
            pose.header.frame_id = "map";
            pose.pose.position.x = cartesian_waypoints[i][0];
            pose.pose.position.y = cartesian_waypoints[i][1];
            pose.pose.position.z = 0.0;
            pose.pose.orientation.x = 0.0;
            pose.pose.orientation.y = 0.0;
            pose.pose.orientation.z = 0.0;
            pose.pose.orientation.w = 1.0;
            
            RCLCPP_INFO(node_->get_logger(), "Added interpolated point (x: %f, y: %f) to plan", cartesian_waypoints[i][0], cartesian_waypoints[i][1]);
            plan.poses.push_back(pose);
        }

        return plan;
    }
```

Any clue on why this error arises and how to solve it? I'm using ros2 humble.

Thanks in advance.